# Prevent slide down sub-menu from sliding up when clicking on next menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

I have a slide down menu that has links in the sub-menu, when I click on another link in the menu I want the sub-menu links to fade in while the others fade out (without closing and opening again). Currently, when I click on another menu item, the sub-menu slides up then back down to reveal the items in that sub-menu.

Here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EGp35/1/. Feel free to structure the code better if needed. Also, the only active links are "shows" and "films". Thanks!

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#shows').click(function(e) {
        $('.sub-menu-1').slideToggle(200);
        $('.sub-menu-2').hide();
            return false; // prevent default click action from happening!
            e.preventDefault(); // same thing as above
    });
});


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#films').click(function(e) {
        $('.sub-menu-2').slideToggle(200);
        $('.sub-menu-1').hide();
            return false; // prevent default click action from happening!
            e.preventDefault(); // same thing as above
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
   $('.sub-menu-1').slideToggle(200);
   $('.sub-menu-2').hide();
```

with

```
  $('.sub-menu-1').slideDown();
  $('.sub-menu-2').slideUp();
```

[Here the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EGp35/3/)

Comment: I need the sub-menu items to fade in and out and the menu to close if the same item is clicked similar to the way it does now.